# How to append the form element with the radio button?

Tags: angular, forms, radio-button, angular6, onchange

I am having two radio Buttons as given in the example Image

[image]

I want to append the next form content on the basis of selection of the checkbox.

> Eg: If New Group is selected than I'll give the input box (Name & Id
>   groupname).
>
> If Existing Group is selected I'll give a drop-down value with all the existing values in the database.

I know How to do it using normal jquery & Html But I don't know how to do it using ANGULAR 7

**EIDT**

I already tried with the below post but it is not working for me

> [Angular2 - Show/Hide section on selection of radio button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45286978/angular2-show-hide-section-on-selection-of-radio-button)

I tried this also but I want some other way to do it.

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-append-prepend

Here is one more thing That I want to mention

> Note: I don't want to implement the hide & show feature I want to append the
>   element because don't want to do the code to validate separate
>   elements on the selection basis.
>
> I am not using the reactive form.

Comment: This talk might help you on how to display content based on form selection : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iqXiic6hE9U

Comment: I have updated my question I know the norms of posting a question on the stack exchange & I did the prior required research before asking the question here.

Comment: Simply start doing a downvote people can ask for the research I did & things I already tried to update to my post

Answer (score 0):

You can hide DOM element with checkbox in nested Angular Reactive Form approach
use this to find a way

[use this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k8macu?file=src/app/app.component.html)